# Invalid use of group function for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting this error but I don't understand why my query doesn't work.  Can someone please give me a hand?

The question is this:
[image]

[image]

```
SELECT activity
FROM Friends
GROUP BY activity
HAVING COUNT(activity) > MIN(COUNT(activity))
AND COUNT(activity) < MAX(COUNT(activity))
```

My idea is that as long as the count of the activity is larger than the activity that has the minimum count and less than the activity that has the maximum count, it should be returned.  But I am having "Invalid use of group function" error which I don't understand.  One possible thing that I could think of is that the parts that I am comparing with the COUNT(activity) have to be a number that is selected from the table instead of a part that has "MIN" or "MAX".  But I don't understand why as they both look like the same number to me.

Comment: Nested aggregate functions not supported. Correct solution highly depends on MySQL version (anycase the solution which uses subquery will work).

Comment: Hi Akina, so what you mean is that I cannot have COUNT in aggregate functions like MIN or MAX?

Comment: first step would be get the count of participants by the activity.

Following which we can rank them on the basis of the top most count of particpiants and least count of participants

Finally we need only those participants who are not the top ranking and the bottom ranking

Comment: You're right when both functions are aggregate. This is legal when outer function is window one (but not in WHERE clause).

Comment: PS. Don't forget to consider the case when some Activity is absent in Friends at all - it has MIN participants in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of MySql is less than 8.0, the following will work:

```
select activity, count(*) as cnt from Friends group by activity
having cnt not in (
  select max(cnt) as cnt from (
    select activity, count(*) as cnt from Friends group by activity
  ) sq1
  union
  select min(cnt) as cnt from (
    select activity, count(*) as cnt from Friends group by activity
  ) sq2
);
```

| activity | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| Singing | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u8iZtYM37cH2a7SKLuTkMc/0)

Since the above SQL references the same select 3 times, namely `select activity, count(*) as cnt from Friends group by activity`, you might consider creating a quasi-temporary table (but there is the overhead in creating such a table to consider -- for the number of rows you actually presented, this would run more slowly):

```
create table t as select activity, count(*) as cnt from Friends group by activity;
select activity from t where cnt not in (
    select max(cnt) as cnt from t
    union
    select min(cnt) as cnt from t
);
drop table t;
```

| activity |
| --- |
| Singing |

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fiVzFQETtAPsfjWZsaTjVH/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want data from friends table then you can use the analytical function (My sql 8.0 or higher) as follows:

```
select activity from
(SELECT activity, dense_rank() over (order by count(*)) as rn_asc,
        dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rn_desc
   FROM Friends
GROUP BY activity)
where rn_asc <> 1 and rn_dsc <> 1
```